# java: about counting in txt file

Tags: java

i want to counting some words in txt file
myfile.txt

```
ABC,xyzwegwegwe
ABC,12312312312
ABC,sdfsdf3sdfs
```

how can i count the words"ABC"?
output:`"ABC" have: 3`

```
while (myfile.hasNextLine()) {
            line = myfile.nextLine();
            lines.add(line);
                    if(xxxxx){ //if have ABC, words++
                        words++; 
                    }
        }
System.out.print("\"ABC\" have: "+words);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you are trying to do is (and if it only has one copy of "ABC" per line)

```
if(line.contains("ABC"))
{
   words++;
}


String lineToTest = "ABC , sdq2we9ieorwq , EFG"

if(line.contains("ABC"))
{
   words++;
}

if(line.contains("EFG"))
{
  words++;
}
```

Notice that this will not check for dupliates!!!

Comment: it work, can i count multiple words?
example: count "ABC", "EFG"

Comment: @heyman do you have some sort of distinction or definition of what a "word" is?

Comment: example: count "ABC" and "EFG" in the file
using one if() statement, my english not good:]

Comment: @heyman the simpliest thing to do is add another if statement to check for efg. once again this is going to work if you only have one EFG and one ABC, you will need to parse if you don;'t